# How to tell `links` to ignore expired SSL certificate and proceed?

Tags: browser, ssl, ssl-certificate, links

I'm using the `links` browser and trying to connect to an HTTPS site. I then get:

```
Verification failure: certificate has expired
```

this is "fine" (i.e. was decided to be tolerated) for this internal-only service, and other browsers allow to dismiss the error and try again.

How can I achieve the same in `links` and ignore the condition, that is: create an exception about the validity of this certificate.

Comment: [Links SSL Error](http://superuser.com/q/839780)

Answer (score 2):

I've used this version for testing:

[links](http://links.twibright.com/download/binaries/win32/Links-2.12-64bit-install.exe) from [twibright labs](http://links.twibright.com/)

Just tried with the argument :

```
links.exe https://expired.badssl.com/ -ssl.certificates 0
```

And the alert is not coming, so Is a kind of creating an exception.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but that "RTFM" isn't very kind. I hope you realize that there are various versions of `links` floating around. I can hardly post the complete `man` page here, but links: [`links2(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/links2.1.html) and [`links(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/links.1.html) and [`links2(1)` for Debian](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=links&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+8+jessie&format=html&locale=en). Please be so kind *where* in those `man` pages I did not read thoroughly enough.

Comment: My `links2` doesn't have this option (Ubuntu 14.04)